# What .Net assemblies are integrated into the SQL Server 2008 R2 CLR as standard?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, clr

I have an existing assembly that has been used within SQL Server for some time. Today I added some experimental code that references `System.Data.Linq`. Creating the assembly within **SQL 2008 R2** resulted in this error:

> *Assembly 'system.data.linq, version=3.5.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089.' was not found in the SQL catalog.*

This is not entirely unexpected, but I was wondering how to determine what the full set of standard '**core**' assembles is within 2008 R2. Presumably `System.Data.Linq` isn't one of them - but I would like to confirm this and also confirm what assemblies are provided as standard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, `System.Data.Linq` isn't integrated into the SQL Server 2008 R2 CLR as standard.

However, the following libraries are ([List sourced from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403279.aspx)):

> CustomMarshalers
>
> Microsoft.VisualBasic
>
> Microsoft.VisualC
>
> mscorlib
>
> System
>
> System.Configuration
>
> System.Data
>
> System.Data.OracleClient
>
> System.Data.SqlXml
>
> System.Deployment
>
> System.Security
>
> System.Transactions
>
> System.Web.Services
>
> System.Xml
>
> System.Core.dll
>
> System.Xml.Linq.dll

Comment: How to add it even if it's unsupported? The MSDN link you provided above says it can be done.